# Save the filters from a store and then put them back

Tags: filter, sencha-touch

If I have applied different filters on a store, how cand I get them all and save them in an Array? I want to remove all the filters from a store, get an item (to remove it) and then put back all the filters that were before. Thanks!

Comment: post the code.. what you tried

Answer (score 0):

If i am understood correctly, you can do

```
var filters = store.getFilters();  // Get the filters using getFilters

store.clearFilter();     // Clear the filters from store     

var item = store.findRecord('fieldName', 'value'); //Get the item from store       

if (item) store.remove(item); //Remove the item from store    

store.setFilters(filters);  // Again set the filters using setFilters
```

**Doc reference**

[getFilters()](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-getFilters)

[clearFilter()](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-clearFilter)

[setFilters()](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-setFilters)

Just a reference in documentation may solved your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this but it doesn't seem to put back the filters when I call store.setFilters(fiiters).

Comment: any error ? and console.log(store) to see its filter configuration

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

```
// Get the filters using getFilters
var filters = store.getFilters(); 

// Clear the filters from store         
store.clearFilter();    

//Get the item from store
var item = store.findRecord('fieldName', 'value');        

 //Remove the item from store    
 if (item) store.remove(item);

// Again set the filters using setFilters  
store.filter(filters);
```